# Binding IPv4 and IPv6 socket failure

Tags: linux, sockets, ip

I installed a license server for a software and run this server on a Linux machine. The execution of the license server is something like:

```
./exefile -logfile log -loglevel 4
```

where I ask all log info to be written in the file named `log`.

Everything is running smoothly but when checking the file `log`, I see the error messages:

```
"Binding IPv4 socket" "Failure.  Socket 16286 probably already in use"
"Binding IPv6 socket" "Failure.  Socket 16287 probably already in use"
```

It seems that this error makes it impossible for the server to record the ip addresses of the machines who (successfully) run the program but I cannot understand the message or find how to solve this error...

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: did you check if anything's bound to 16286?

Comment: the thing is that I really have no idea what the error message means. I don't know how to check this...

Comment: only one process can bind to a port (e.g. use it) at a time, so the error says some OTHER program is possibly already using 16286. Use `netstat -a` to see what's all using ports on your system.

Comment: thanks, so I see something like:
**tcp        0      0 \*:16286                 *:\*                     LISTEN** which is not very informative... it does not give me a process name as I would expect.

Comment: `-p` will also list the program using the socket. but yeah, that netstat output means something's already running/listening on the socket. maybe you've already run the license server and a copy's already there.

Comment: indeed, so it does show the name of the license server actually. Ok, I found the problem, the license server created a process that used both sockets when I ran it the first time (before adding log options). After killing the process and restarting it, everything is fine. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so to sum up, thanks to Marc's comments I was able to see that the first run of the license server created a process that was using sockets 16286 and 16287 using the command:

```
netstat -ap
```

After killing this process and restarting the license server, everything works well.